# Find a value which contains in ALL rows of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I need to select all values which are contained in ALL rows of a table.
I have table “Ingredient” and ProductIngredient(there I have a recipe of a product).
Ingredient

```
| ingredient_id | name | price | 
| 1             | Bla  | 100   
| 2             | foo  | 50
```

ProductIngredient.

```
| Product_id | ingredient_id
| 1          | 1   
| 1          | 2   
| 2          | 1
```

The output should be

```
|  1   |  Bla |
```

as it is in all rows of ProductIngredient.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Ingredient_Id 
FROM Ingredients I
WHERE Ingredient_Id = ALL
    (SELECT Ingredient_id FROM ProductIngredient PI
     WHERE PI.Ingredient_Id = I.Ingredient_Id );
```

How can I fix my code to make it work?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your question statement is not clear.  For instance, the question appears to be about a single table, but the sample code references two.

Comment: Please tag properly!!!  Which one is it, MySQL or Postgres?????  Can't be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you all Ingredients from I that are in PI for each product. This is assuming that each product does not have multiple rows for a product and ingredient combination.

```
SELECT I.Ingredient_Id 
FROM Ingredients I INNER JOIN ProductIngredient PI
     ON PI.Ingredient_Id = I.Ingredient_Id
GROUP BY I.Ingredient_Id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Product_id) FROM ProductIngredient)
```

Comment: Yes, but I need only that ingredients from I that contains in every product(PI)

Comment: Do you mean like a group by for each product? Or do you want the ingredients that are in all the products?

Comment: Yeah, the ingredients that are in all products (:

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope this helps.